# How to search by PrimaryGroupToken in Ldap?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, unboundid

I have following snippet

```
val entry = ldapConnectionPool.getEntry(groupNn, SearchRequest.ALL_USER_ATTRIBUTES, "PrimaryGroupToken")
val primaryGroupToken = entry.getAttributeValue("PrimaryGroupToken")
```

primaryGroupToken is equal `550` after execution

Then I want to find the same entry by `PrimaryGroupToken`

```
ldapConnectionPool.searchForEntry(SearchRequest(dn, SearchScope.SUB, "PrimaryGroupToken=$primaryGroupToken"))
```

but it returns `null`. Is there way to find entry by `PrimaryGroupToken`  ?